Invalid JSON blob: unknown field `allianceMotion`
I am trying to generate raw json file but encounter with this error
./target/release/dip-consumer-node-template build-spec --chain plain-parachain-chainspec.json --disable-default-bootnode --raw > raw-parachain-chainspec.json
2024-08-15 15:40:58 Building chain spec    
Error: Service(Other("Invalid JSON blob: unknown field `allianceMotion`, expected one of `system`, `babe`, `indices`, `balances`, `transactionPayment`, `session`, `grandpa`, `authorityDiscovery`, `treasury`, `claims`, `society`, `vesting`, `nisCounterpartBalances`, `configuration`, `paras`, `hrmp`, `registrar`, `xcmPallet`, `beefy`, `assignedSlots`, `sudo` at line 1 column 17"))

Generating plain spect file is fine but what is wrong with raw json file? Can someone please suggest what is happening here?
github_code

The expected strings are listing out the pallets included in your runtime.
It seems that allianceMotion is not a pallet included in the runtime inside your node, and thus rejects this field when trying to add it to genesis.
